# distribution of errors: standard deviation for single raster file in R

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I have a single raster for which I want to calculate the

1. Root Mean Square Error (RMSE)
2. Mean Error
3. Absolute Mean Error
4. Standard Deviation

```
library(r)
r <- raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"))
```

For the RMSE and the (absolute) mean error I need some kind of predicted values (?) how do i calculate/get them?

For the standard deviation i could just write

```
sd(r)
```

but that give me the error

```
Error in as.double(x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'
```

I've looked for a while and only found solutions working for raster stacks which will then return another raster. But I don't want that. For each of the 4 measurements I want a single number to return me the value of what was calculated.

Comment: Here's a [resource](https://rspatial.org/raster/spatial/8-rastermanip.html) on how to handle rasters, but a raster is essentially a grid of values. It won't have an "error" unless you compare 2 rasters or a raster to an interpolated layer or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's create data with a known standard deviation:

```r
set.seed(69)

m <- matrix(rnorm(10000), nrow = 100)

sd(m)
#> [1] 0.9979821
```

Now we can turn this into a raster:

```r
library(raster)

r <- raster(m)

r
#> class      : RasterLayer 
#> dimensions : 100, 100, 10000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#> resolution : 0.01, 0.01  (x, y)
#> extent     : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : NA 
#> source     : memory
#> names      : layer 
#> values     : -3.507427, 3.669151  (min, max)
```

If you want to get the original data's values you can use the `data` slot:

```
sd(r@data@values)
#> [1] 0.9979821
```

Or, more compactly, use the subsetting operator `[]`:

```r
sd(r[])
#> [1] 0.9979821
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

while

```
sd(r[])
```

kind of worked, it returned NA, but by adding "na.rm = TRUE" it worked fine.
Another answer could have been:

```
sd(as.matrix(r), na.rm = TRUE)
```

which I assume does essentially the same. the first option reads the data, whereas the second first transforms the data into a matrix.

Comment: if you go this route,  I would do `sd(values(r), na.rm=TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

There is the `cellStats` method for that

```
set.seed(69)
m <- matrix(rnorm(10000), nrow = 100)
sd(m)
#[1] 0.9979821

library(raster)
r <- raster(m)    
cellStats(r, sd)
#[1] 0.9979821
```

Or, with `terra`, the `global` method

```
library(terra)
x <- rast(m)
global(x, sd)
#         global
#lyr.1 0.9979821
```